# What happening behind scene when we want to render view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ActionResult is the base class for the various return types to View in MVC. So your action must return an ActionResult or a class derived from it in order to work.

so we can use

```
public ContentResult Index()
{
    return Content("Hello world");
}
```

or for example

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

or ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (ViewBag.Hello = "World")
        return Json("");
    return PartialView();
}
```

BUT also is possible use string !!!

```
public string Index()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

WHY is than not possible return integer to view? (Or maybe it is?)

```
public int Index()
{
    return 4;
}
```

and not possible return some entity to view (Or maybe it is?)

```
public User Index()
{
    return new User();
}
```

My question is : What happening behind scene when we want to render view?

Comment: I think the question is too broad for a proper answer. You can start by looking at the [lifecycle and pipeline of MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application).

Comment: What do your questions _"WHY is than not possible return integer to view? (Or maybe it is?)"_ and _"and not possible return some entity to view (Or maybe it is?)"_ mean? Did you try it? What were the results? _"What happening behind scene when we want to render view?"_ is too broad anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this is quite a broad question, but I wanted address and answer a few of the points you raised in your question.

You can return an `int`, `string` or `object` from your action method and it will simply return the object's string representation as the result.

Therefore you don't have to return an object of type `ActionResult` in order for it to work, but the `ActionResult` enables useful functionality through it's various implementations so that ASP.NET MVC Framework can handle different scenarios straight out of the box.

Such as returning views and handling the ViewModel you want to pass to your view:

```
return View(); // Default view without view model
return View(viewModelObject); // Default view with a view model
```

Returning views based on your routing information:

```
return View("viewName", viewModelObject);
```

Performing redirects to another page, using your routing information:

```
return RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName);
```

Returning a page with specific status codes:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

Returning JSON instead of a view:

```
return JsonResult(myObject);
```

All of the above examples do different things, return different types of results and handle your objects for you so that you don't have to code the behaviour yourself - they're ready for you to use.

Another handy thing is that you can create your own implementations of `ActionResult` to create your own behaviour, so it's very flexible in that regard.

I agree with `@Daniel J.G.` that you should do some more reading on how ASP.NET MVC hangs together and it will become a lot more clear to you.

Comment: Is it possible pass ViewModel  to View without using ActionResult type ?

Comment: No. Returning something like a string, int, etc. is functionally the same as returning `Content(someString)`. MVC just casts the return into a string and then sends it straight down the pipe to the client as the response. You don't get any views, models, etc.